# $S(f,P) < \overline{\int_a^b} f(x) dx + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, Darboux integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

$$\overline{\int_a^b}f(x)dx = inf \ S(f,P)$$

where is $s(f, P) = m_i(t_1-t_0)+\cdots +m_n(t_n-t_{n-1})$ and $m_i=\inf\{f(x), t_{i-1}\le x\le t_i\}$. I need to prove that:

$$S(f,P) < \overline{\int_a^b} f(x) dx + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

that is:

$$S(f,P) < \inf \ S(f,P) + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

remember that $S(f, P) = M_i(t_1-t_0)+\cdots +M_n(t_n-t_{n-1})$ where $M_i=\sup\{f(x), \le t_{i-1}x\le t_i\}$

How to even begin with such hard proof?

I know there's a theorem that asks me to prove that

$$S(f,P) < s(f,P) + \epsilon$$

but here I need to prove with the sup of the inf, which is not the same thing.

Comment: There is some typo in your question. Please check the exact usage of $\inf$ and $\sup$ in your question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I can't find one...

Comment: The question doesn't make sense as written. Are you assuming $f$ is Darboux-integrable? If not, then the identity you are trying to prove might not be true. Please read up on the Darboux integral: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral and try to rephrase your question.

Comment: Here is my guess: Do you want to show that given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a partition $P$ such that $S(f,P) < \overline{\int_a^b} f(x) dx + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$? If so, this is just the definition of infimum in the definition of the upper Darboux integral.

Comment: This question needs rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a mistake, (possibly a typo). In order to correctly define the Darboux integral you need to have one supremum and one infimum... either you take the biggest lower bound or you consider the least upper bound. So you have 2 ways to correct your question: either change $m_i$ to be $ \sup\{f(x), t_{i-1}<x\leq t_i\}$ or you consider the integral to be the $\sup$ of $S(f,P)$.

In both cases, when you correcct your definition you'll see that the claim you're trying to state is a direct consequence from the definition of the supremum or infimum.